# apache user can't stat a path from CGI, but can from shell

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions

Here is a script to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");

  printf("UID, EUID = %d, %d\n", getuid(), geteuid());
  printf("GID, EGID = %d, %d\n", getgid(), getegid());

  struct stat stbuf;
  if (stat("/dev/shm", &stbuf))
    printf("stat() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  else
    printf("stat() succeeded\n");

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this script under a `sudo su -s /bin/bash apache` shell, it produces:

```
Content-Type: text/plain

UID, EUID = 48, 48
GID, EGID = 48, 48
stat() succeeded
```

But when run as a CGI script by Apache/2.2, the page responds:

```
UID, EUID = 48, 48
GID, EGID = 48, 48
stat() failed: Permission denied
```

How is this possible? The location in question (/dev/shm) on this machine these permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root   root       260 Mar 29 06:52 .
drwxr-xr-x. 20 root   root      4300 Mar 28 10:31 ..
```

Comment: Is SELinux in enforcing mode? Find out using `sestatus`. If it is, you can find out if it is the cause of your problems by temporarily disabling it with `setenforce 0` and trying to run your script again. I'll post a complete solution if SELinux is the cause.

Comment: It is enabled. After issuing `setenforce 0`, the `stat()` call succeeds.

Comment: Is your script located in the `/var/www/cgi-bin/` directory? If it isn't, try moving it there. Then try running `restorecon -R /var/www/cgi-bin/` and `setenforce 1` to see if that properly fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to selinux.

Your script is not permitted to do a stat on `tmpfs_t` as the `httpd_sys_script_t` type. This is by design. Depending on what you are trying to stat() (not just /dev/shm) can depend on what action you might want to take.

If you `chcon` the program to run in the label `httpd_unconfined_script_exec_t` this will avoid SELinux restrictions, at the cost of no SELinux protections whatsoever for the script being ran.

Comment: Right. Don't disable SELinux in this scenario. It's doing what it's supposed to do.